# Rails HTML to PDF using puppeteer (headless chrome), how to send html to puppeteer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puppeteer

I have a rails app that uses the code below to download a PDF from an HTML page. It works fine, but it's slow because it's loading a page before saving it to PDF.

How can I send it HTML directly from my Rails server, so it doesn't need to load a url? Is there some way to render to string and send that through? Or do I need to render to a file, then send its path through?

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def pdf
    tmp = Tempfile.new("tmp/pdf-chrome-puppeteer")
    system("yarn createPDF #{Shellwords.escape("https://google.com")} #{Shellwords.escape(tmp.path)}")
    pdf_filename = "output.pdf"
    send_file(tmp.path, filename: pdf_filename, type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'attachment')
  end
end
```

My JS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const createPdf = async() => {
  const startTime = new Date().getTime();
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(process.argv[2], {timeout: 30000, waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.pdf({
      path: process.argv[3],
      format: 'A4',
      margin: { top: 36, right: 36, bottom: 20, left: 36 },
      printBackground: true
    });
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      browser.close();
    }
    process.exit();
  }
};
```

Comment: Probably save it to a file and pass the filename, but the assets will be all messed up if you do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the gem for this. This has bundled all the stuffs https://github.com/Studiosity/grover

Answer (score 0):

You can store the html in a `string` or `TempFile`.

```
   view = ActionView::Base.new Rails.configuration.paths['app/views']     
   view.assign(model_name: model_instance)
   html = view.render file: 'path/to/view'
```